# Calling timer in a loop in Corona SDK

Tags: timer, lua, coronasdk

To call a timer infinite times I am using

```
function A()
    print("Hello")
    timer.performWithDelay(100, B, 1)
end

function B()
    timer.performWithDelay(500, A, 1)
end

timer.performWithDelay(100, A, 1)
```

So that If I want to print hello in a particular time interval, I am adjusting it with these two functions.
But the problem I am facing is after some time the timer gets slow down and calling function A very rapidly.
Can anyone suggest me If I am doing this right? And to resolve the timer issue what should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call a timer infinite times, you can use either:

```
timer.performWithDelay(100, functionName, -1)
```

or

```
timer.performWithDelay(100, functionName, 0)
```

In your case, you need to cancel the timers before calling it again. So, do like follows:

```
local timer_1,timer_2,timer_3
function A()
    print("Hello")
    if(timer_1)then timer.cancel(timer_1) end  -- cancelling 'timer_1' if exists
    if(timer_3)then timer.cancel(timer_3) end  -- cancelling 'timer_3' if exists
    timer_2 = timer.performWithDelay(100, B, 1) 
end

function B()
    if(timer_2)then timer.cancel(timer_2) end  -- cancelling 'timer_2' if exists
    timer_3 = timer.performWithDelay(500, A, 1)
end

timer_1 = timer.performWithDelay(100, A, 1)
```

Here you can see that, I've created timer objects(timer_1,timer_2 and timer_3), and cancel timers which are possibly in progress, before calling another/same timer.

Keep Coding............. :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but still it is giving the same problem.

Comment: @Akshada-Systematix: Also try cancelling all other timers before calling next. That will do it.